# SQL query for calculating work hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a query that gathers people times on a clock in/out system, and orders them to the correct day as these are nigh shift, so span two days, here is the query and out put

```
SELECT 
    china_vision_pubpersonnel.NAME, 
    china_vision_pubpersonnel.id, 
    china_vision_pubcards.cardcode, 
    china_vision_pubpersonnel.telephone, 
    atdshiftdetail.endoverday, 
    china_vision_dorevents.eventtm AS T, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), china_vision_dorevents.eventtm, 103) AS Day, 
    Floor(CONVERT(FLOAT, Dateadd(hour, 4, eventtm))) AS DayNumber,
    Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Floor(CONVERT(FLOAT, Floor(CONVERT(FLOAT, Dateadd(hour, 6, eventtm))))) 
                      ORDER BY Floor(CONVERT(FLOAT, Dateadd(hour, 5, eventtm)))) InDay 
FROM   
    china_vision_pubcards 
INNER JOIN 
    china_vision_pubpersonnel ON china_vision_pubcards.pubpersonnel_ref = china_vision_pubpersonnel.reference 
INNER JOIN 
    china_vision_dorevents ON china_vision_pubcards.cardcode = china_vision_dorevents.cardcode 
INNER JOIN 
    atdshiftdetail ON RIGHT(china_vision_pubpersonnel.id, 4) = atdshiftdetail.NAME 
WHERE  
    (china_vision_dorevents.dorctrls_ref = '16') 
    AND (CONVERT(DATE, china_vision_dorevents.eventtm) > Dateadd(day, -730, Getdate())) 
    AND atdshiftdetail.endoverday = '1'
```

Results of this query most of the column names are self explanatory However

T is the Time of input

Day is the day of that input

Day number is a list of days put in to a number, as you can each each day that is the same has the same number

InDay is the order of the inputs,  so as you can see 1 is always at night 2 and 3 are going and coming back from brake, and 4 is leaving

```
    Name  | ID  | CardCode | Telephone | EndOverDay  |           T (Time)        |   Day        |  DayNumber  | InDay
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-10 07:52:00.000 | 10/02/2017   |    42774    |  4
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-10 03:28:31.000 | 10/02/2017   |    42774    |  3
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-10 02:57:14.000 | 10/02/2017   |    42774    |  2
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-09 19:18:19.000 | 09/02/2017   |    42773    |  1
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-09 07:50:55.000 | 09/02/2017   |    42773    |  4
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-09 03:28:41.000 | 09/02/2017   |    42773    |  3
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-09 02:56:14.000 | 09/02/2017   |    42773    |  2
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-08 19:19:05.000 | 08/02/2017   |    42772    |  1
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-08 07:43:06.000 | 08/02/2017   |    42772    |  4
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-08 03:26:33.000 | 08/02/2017   |    42772    |  3
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-08 02:54:58.000 | 08/02/2017   |    42772    |  2
    Name  | ID  | CardCode |    9      |    1        |   2017-02-07 19:15:46.000 | 07/02/2017   |    42771    |  1
```

So the End goal should be adding the Indays  1-2 together, 3-4 together and then those two results to get the total for that day

The day is the day that Inday 1 lands on

Comment: What are you summing here? Total hours worked in one shift? To keep your current query you will need to add two more levels of abstraction, one to get  a sum of values grouped by employee, date, and your InDay calculation and a second to sum by employee and date.

Comment: Exactly, so for Daynumber 42773 it would be the difference between InDay 1 and 2, and then the difference between InDay 3-4 and then those two results combined for the total time

Comment: Assuming you just want the results of this query through sql server, insert the results of this query to a temp table and follow what Ross said.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys, i'm not that great with SQL do you have any examples i could look at? or a resource i can read though

Comment: "Select" your query "into" a "#TempTable" . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx or Create a temporary table first http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables Then you could query the #TempTable and group on the fields you want.

Comment: How would you calculate the aggregates if your results were in a table in the format above? It would be pretty easy, you have already got the hard work out of the way, you just need to roll up the values one or two steps further. You can do what josh stated above, push results into a temp table and query from that. You can also wrap your query with one or two outer queries to do basically the same thing. What you want is SELECT SUM(DETAIL.DetailField) FROM (<YOUR QUERY ABOVE>) AS DETAIL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with your data and temp tables. This should get you started. Obviously needs some work for your results.

```
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable ( 
                            EmpName         VARCHAR(10)
                            , ID            INT
                            , CardCode      VARCHAR(10)
                            , Telephone     VARCHAR(10)
                            , EndOverDay    int
                            , T             DATETIME
                            , TDay          DATETIME
                            , DayNumber     BIGINT
                            , InDay         INT
                        )

INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Rick Flair',   1,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-10 07:52:00.000',  '10/02/2017',   42774,  4)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Rick Flair', 1,    'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-10 03:28:31.000',  '10/02/2017',   42774,  3)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Rick Flair',   1,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-10 02:57:14.000',  '10/02/2017',   42774,  2)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Rick Flair',   1,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-09 19:18:19.000',  '09/02/2017',   42773,  1)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Scott Hall',   2,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-09 07:50:55.000',  '09/02/2017',   42773,  4)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Scott Hall',   2,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-09 03:28:41.000',  '09/02/2017',   42773,  3)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Scott Hall',   2,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-09 02:56:14.000',  '09/02/2017',   42773,  2)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Scott Hall',   2,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-08 19:19:05.000',  '08/02/2017',   42772,  1)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Kevin Nash',   3,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-08 07:43:06.000',  '08/02/2017',   42772,  4)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Kevin Nash',   3,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-08 03:26:33.000',  '08/02/2017',   42772,  3)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Kevin Nash',   3,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-08 02:54:58.000',  '08/02/2017',   42772,  2)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('Kevin Nash',   3,  'CardCode', 9,  1,  '2017-02-07 19:15:46.000',  '07/02/2017',   42771,  1)


SELECT A.EmpName, SUM(A.HoursWorked) AS HoursWorked
FROM (
        SELECT t1.EmpName, t1.id, t1.t AS Time1, t2.t AS Time2, datediff(HOUR, t1.t, t2.t) AS HoursWorked
        FROM #TempTable t1
            JOIN (
                    SELECT EmpName ,
                           ID ,
                           CardCode ,
                           Telephone ,
                           EndOverDay ,
                           T ,
                           TDay ,
                           DayNumber ,
                           InDay
                    FROM #TempTable 
                    WHERE InDay = 2
                ) t2 ON
                t1.id = t2.id
        WHERE t1.InDay = 1

        UNION all

        SELECT t1.EmpName, t1.id, t1.t AS Time1, t2.t AS Time2, datediff(HOUR, t1.t, t2.t) AS HoursWorked
        FROM #TempTable t1
            JOIN (
                    SELECT EmpName ,
                           ID ,
                           CardCode ,
                           Telephone ,
                           EndOverDay ,
                           T ,
                           TDay ,
                           DayNumber ,
                           InDay
                    FROM #TempTable 
                    WHERE InDay = 4
                ) t2 ON
                t1.id = t2.id
        WHERE t1.InDay = 3
    ) A
GROUP BY A.EmpName;


DROP TABLE #TempTable
```